# How to write SQL for combination of AND?

Tags: sql, select, ecto

Please check the attached table.

[image]

I need to write a query to get documents which have both `tage_id` of say 32 and 26.

Something like `select * from doc_tags where tag_id = 32 or tag_id = 26` is not going to work as I will get both documents with 32, 26, and ( 32, 26 ).

**I need documents which only have tag id 32 **and** 26 not individual.**

**NOTE**
I can't use the `document_id` as a reference.

Comment: hello, which  output require?

Comment: What do you mean by `type`

Comment: tag_id= 32 & 26  record output require?

Comment: so as long as I can get the documents which have tags 32 and 26 would do the job

Comment: What DBMS is being used?

Comment: Postgresql.....

Comment: If as you say you can't reference the document_id , then you won't be able to tie together the different instances of tag_id to identify documents having both 26 and 32. It might be helpful to know why you think you can't reference the document_id .

Comment: ... your accepted answer DOES reference the document_id by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from doc_tags dt1
where (
    select count(distinct tag_id) from doc_tags dt2
    where dt2.document_id = dt1.document_id and tag_id in (26, 32)
) = 2 and dt1.tag_id in (26, 32)
```

or

```
with data as (
    select *,
        count(distinct tag_id) over (partition by document_id) as matches
    from doc_tags where tag_id in (26, 32)
)
select * from data where matches = 2
```

Comment: I get document with tag 25 and 27 too!

Comment: Yes @MrH, I have no idea how you wanted to filter the final results.

Comment: Thank you. Now I need to convert this to Elixir Ecto :). Thanks again

Comment: @shawnt00, your CTE will not work correctly because you have no group by for the count. So you need a group by, and specify maybe document_id in there and then join it up eg `;with data as (
    select document_id, count(distinct tag_id) as matches
    from doc_tags where tag_id in (26, 32)
  group by document_id
)
select b.* from data a 
join doc_tags b on a.document_id = b.document_id 
where matches = 2 and tag_id in (26, 32)`

Comment: @Jacques. Yeah, that was too hastily edited. If you look at edit history you'll see it was previously written to return all tags.

Answer (score 1):

I'd count the number of **different** tags the document has between those two:

```
SELECT   document_id
FROM     doc_tags
WHERE    tag_id IN (26, 32)
GROUP BY document_id
HAVING   COUNT(DISTINCT tag_id) = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is only going to be between 2 documents, you can do this

```
Select * 
from doc_tags a
join doc_tags b on a.document_id = b.document_id
where a.tag_id = 26 and b.tag_id = 32
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this type of SQL query:

```
select * 
from doc_tags 
where tag_id in (32,26)
```

Comment: Nope, it will return based on `or` not `and` I need to return documents which have 32 and 26

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @RESULT TABLE(doc_name VARCHAR(255))

INSERT INTO @RESULT 
       SELECT document_id 
       from doc_tags 
       WHERE tag_id =26 AND document_id IN 
            (SELECT document_id 
             from #tmp 
             WHERE tag_id =32)

SELECT * 
FROM doc_tags 
WHERE document_id in (SELECT doc_name 
                      FROM @RESULT)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM doc_tags WHERE tag_id = 32 and tag_id = 26
```

The above will only return tag_id's 32 and 26

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  d1.*
FROM
  doc_tags AS d1
INNER JOIN
  doc_tags AS d2
ON
  d1.documentid = d2.documentid AND
  (
    d1.documentid = 26 AND d2.documentid = 32 OR
    d1.documentid = 32 AND d2.documentid = 26
  )
WHERE
  d1.id <> d2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `min()/max()` function :

```
SELECT document_id
FROM doc_tags dt
WHERE tag_id IN (26, 32)
GROUP BY document_id
HAVING MIN(tag_id) <> MAX(tag_id);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select * from doc_tags where tag_id not in (32, 26)
```

Comment: There are better ways of doing this. use `not in (32, 26)` is probably the best one